# How to covert bitmap to byte array using Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm developing an application which will open an image using gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new, get the pixel and convert it to byte array. The converted data will be displayed on the LCD of the reader. I am using Linux C++ (GTK). I've found several documentation about GDK_Pixbuf. I tried those functions which I think give me the data I needed but no luck. Here is one I found [GDK-pixbuf](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html) . Any help would be appreciated.

By the way, I have these code in C++ (windows)

iWidth = picRect.right - picRect.left;
        iHeight = picRect.bottom - picRect.top;

```
    BitBlt(picHDC,0,0,(picRect.right - picRect.left),(picRect.bottom - picRect.top),hDC,0,0,SRCCOPY); 

    int iGraphicsDataCounter = 0;


    COLORREF rgb = ::GetPixel (picHDC, 0, 0);

    UINT uRed = GetRValue (rgb);
    int iSequenceIndex = 0;
    int iCounter = 0;
    byte aSequence[8] = { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };

            for(int iRowIndex = 0; iRowIndex < iHeight; iRowIndex++)
    {
        for(int iColumnIndex = 0; iColumnIndex < iWidth; iColumnIndex++)
        {
            rgb = ::GetPixel (picHDC, iColumnIndex, iRowIndex);
            uRed = GetRValue (rgb);
            if(uRed == 255)
                aGraphicsData[iCounter] |= 0x00;
            else
                aGraphicsData[iCounter] |= aSequence[iSequenceIndex];

            if(++iSequenceIndex == 8)
            {
                iCounter++;
                iSequenceIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bitmap already contains an array of bytes. These bytes are RGB(A) values. So, what exactly is the output of your "conversion"??

Comment: I've modified my inquiry. Sorry bout that. :(

Comment: I think you will need to read something about XWindows development first.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some documentation about Xlib but I'm so unfortunate that I cant get the correct result.

Comment: Why you didn't post that partially ported code?

Comment: What do you mean? I've posted the part of the code which I find difficult to do. Its included in my inquiry already.